# smtp auth with postfix reject with error 'need fully-qualified hostname'

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, smtp

I have some kind of a problem with a mail server consist of postfix + dovecot + roundcube on a debian squeeze.

Sending and receiving mail from roundcube workd perfectly. But I can't send mail from an external client such as outlook. I still can read mail from POP3 or IMAP perfectly. I have always the same error but, I can't find a solution on the internet :

```
client.hostname: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname; from=<testeur2@mail.example.com> to=<testeur2@mail.example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=client.hostname
```

Here is my postfix's main.cf :

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
delay_warning_time = 1h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = coruscant.kilkoa.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = mail.kilkoa.com, 9274hd61061, localhost.localdomain, localhost
#relayhost =
mynetworks = 213.246.61.0/24 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_uid_maps = static:3000
virtual_gid_maps = static:3000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/mailer

virtual_transport = dovecot

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains.cf

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_invalid_hostname

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous


dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Does someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the SMTP transaction when someone is sending you mail, The conversation starts with the person trying to send you mail saying something like this:

```
HELO rmotehostname.domain.com
```

The error you are getting:

```
: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=
```

is saying that the hostname they send is not a fully-qualified hostname.  So instead of sending something like "remotehostname.domain.com" they are sending just "remotehostname.  You reject this because you explicitly set `reject_non_fqdn_hostname` in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, i have'nt seen that, i "sharped" reject_non_fqdn_hostname and it's working.